# Display child divs in full width

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a container with several spans in it but the problem is that the inner containers cannot be displayed in full width ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/683AS/)):

```
test <span class="total">45
    <span class="preview">
        <span class="upc">7 carrots</span>
        <span class="edc">14 nuts</span>
        <span class="poc">21 apples</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.total {
    position: relative;
}
.edc, .upc, .poc {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #74BDDB;
}
.upc {
    top: -1.2em;
    left: 5px;
}
.edc {
    top: 1.7em;
    left: 5px;
}
.poc {
    top: 0.3em;
    left: 100%;
}
```

I tried solving it by defining the absolute width of the inner spans ([*click*](http://jsfiddle.net/683AS/1/)) but it has two drawbacks. First, I have the unwanted padding of spans with shorter content ("nuts") and second, when the number gets larger I have a line break again so using absolute width is not a solution. What can I do?

Comment: My first note is, be carefule, div is different from span! div is a block element by nature while span is an inline element.

Comment: Thanks but I am aware of the difference.

Comment: so which one you prefer span or div for this case? I think it could make a difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to `.edc, .upc, .poc {}`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/683AS/5/)

Comment: Amazing. One line and decent browser support:) This attribute is new for me. Thanks.